# Object detection model's performance jumping up and down

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

I am training a model to detect buildings from satellite images in rural Africa. For labels, I use OpenStreetMap geometries. I use the Tensorflow Object Detection API and SSD Inception V2 as a model. I trained separate models on two different datasets (in different geographical regions). In one area, the model learns and quiet quickly converges:

[image: karonga_f1]

When training the model in the other area, however, this happens:

[image: tabora]

Note that I use the exact same model, configuration, batch size, the training area is of the same size, etc. In the second case, the model's prediction change extremely rapidly and I am not able to see why. For example, here is a comparison of the predictions the model makes at 107k and 108k global steps:

[image: preds]

I am quite new to deep learning and cannot understand why this might happen. I would be very grateful for any tips where to look, etc. It might be something simple that I am overlooking.

Let me know if I should provide more information

Comment: I'm not expert in images or DL so I can only give a general comment: with the 2nd dataset the model is not stable, which probably means that the data contains some kind of noise which prevents the model from identifying the right features with certainty (this would happen for instance if there's not enough data, but that's not the only possible reason).

Comment: I agree with Erwan. Testing some hyperparameters may also increase stability like a decreased learning rate.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that it could be a bad batch that in every epoch turns the training in the wrong direction but I think this is not the case - the performance drops like that for up to several epochs.